# C# Compress a string of characters

Tags: c#, string, compression

Say 1 character is 1Byte, so i have 10 characters, and that is 10Bytes.

I have a sentence which contains of 20 characters and i need to upload this sentence to a server. and the limit is only 10 Bytes, how do i compress this sentence which is 20Bytes to 10Bytes.

Is there anyway i can do this via C# ?

**EDIT**

I have a 170 character sentence, i need to compress it in a way that it seems to be like 130characters. i am uploading this sentence to a 3rd party server, so i dont have any control over the server. Can this be done ?

Comment: Why in the world are you limited to 10 bytes?  Compressing something that small generally makes the result *larger*.

Comment: can you change logic on server?

Comment: Can you send it in chunks of 10 bytes each?

Comment: @Kirk i have edited my question. @Senad No i can't do that @Mark No, i have to send it all togeather, (i have edited the question above) @Henk does it sound like home work :S

Comment: @ille, if you have no control over the server, how is the server going to know how to decompress the text?

Comment: @Kirk yeah, i need to know if we can deceive the server to tell its a 130 character (130bits) string instead of a 170 character (170 bits) string ?

Comment: @ille, that's analogous to saying you want to deceive your bathroom scale into reading a 150 pound person instead of a 250 pound person.  You will have to resort to magic.

Comment: To answer this question we need to know what is going on; is it "a sentence" or is it "20 characters"? Why do you need to "upload it"? To what server? Why is the server's limit 10 bytes? Why do you think compressing it is going to help? What is going to uncompress the sentence? EDIT: What, now it's "170 characters"?? This is getting more confusing every change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want should be possible most of the time, but I can guarantee problems. If you wrote a method using the [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) class, it could take this 170 byte string you have and reduce it.  Like most people have said, the compression ratio really depends on the content itself.

Just as a test: 
I took a string of "0123456789" repeating 17 times (for 170 characters), gzipped it and it reduced to 21 characters.
If I take a string of 170 zeros and gzip it, it gets reduced to 12 characters.
I took 170 bytes of random code, and it gets reduced down to 79 characters.

So in these cases, it would compress it down to fit into your space requirements; but there's no way to predict when and how often it wouldn't.  The compression ratio may end up being 1:1 and there is an inherent overhead in creating the block structure, so it could actually result in compressed length of slightly larger than the original.  Then again, you may have to base64 encode the whole thing to make it store properly in the DB, so that would increase your overhead even more.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can't do it in a *guaranteed* way, no. There are far more possible sequences of 20 bytes than there are sequences of 10 bytes - so you can't possibly compress *every* sequence of 20 bytes reversibly into 10 bytes.

In general compression doesn't typically work very well with very small input lengths.

If you know that all your input will *actually* be (say) A-Z and space (i.e. 27 characters) then that's 5 bits... so you only need 100 bits in total. That's still a bit more than the 80 bits you have available, so you still couldn't *guarantee* to represent all sentences. You could make "common" characters shorter than "unusual" characters though, and get many sentences to work that way.

It's hard to be more specific without knowing what you *really* need to achieve, given the impossibility of the original requirement.

Comment: What i need to do is to compress a 170 character sentence so it looks like a 130 character sentence. and i have no control over the server. Its a 3rd party server that i am trying to send this string.

Comment: But 170 characters of what? give us an idea of the size of the total alphabet.  Can the input be anything on the keyboard or is it limited in some way? A-Z,a-z,0-9, punctuation and whitespace, what are the restrictions?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, compression ratio depends on the content of the string itself.
And even if you can compress the sequence, you must implement the decompression on the server too. But if you have access to the server you can simply divide the sequence in many parts.

Comment: what hapence if i don't have access over the server. I have edited my question above. I need to send a string to the server that appears to be lesser in size. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a serious problem here. Twenty bytes is 160 bits is 2^160 possible messages. Ten bytes is 80 bits is 2^80 possible messages. Unless you have some way to reduce your source message space to only containing 2^80 possible messages, you can not do this.

Answer (score 0):

If the messages are static, pass indices into an array containing the different messages it could be sending instead of passing the messages. If they're dynamic, then it's simply not possible unless you can limit yourself to a limited subset of ASCII and store multiple characters in one byte, or the string is extremely repetitive in which case you could consider [Run-Length Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).

Comment: Run-Length Encoding requires server side processing if i am not mistaken. But i have no control over the server